# How to Call an Implementation contract method using Proxy Address from Contract?

Tags: solidity

I imported the Interface of the implementation contract and instantiated it with the Proxy address but keep getting transaction revert when I call the implementation method. The proxy and logic contract not from my system but from another deployed platform/project.

```
InterfaceOfImplementationContract(proxyAddress).MethodBeingCalled(parameter, parameter, parameter);
```

What am I doing wrong? If I use the implementation contract address, it works. I also tried using call but it seems not to execute or change state.

```
proxyAddress.call.value(msg.value)(abi.encode("executeOrder(address, uint256, uint256)", parameter, parameter, parameter));
```

This is how I deployed the contracts.

```
//ARTIFACTS
const PROXY_CONTRACT = artifacts.require("PROXYCONTRACT");
const IMPLEMENTATION_CONTRACT = artifacts.require("CONTRACT1");
const PROXY_CONTRACT = artifacts.require("AdminUpgradeabilityProxy");


module.exports = (deployer, network, accounts) => {
  deployer
  .deploy(IMPLEMENTATION_CONTRACT)
    
  .then(() => deployer.deploy(PROXY_CONTRACT, IMPLEMENTATION_CONTRACT.address, accounts[0]))
  .then(() => deployer.deploy(
    CONTRACT_WHEREPROXY_IS_CALLED,
    PROXY_CONTRACT.address
  ))
    .then(async () => {

      console.log("\nGetting contract instances...");
      
      CONTRACT_WHEREPROXY_IS_CALLED.initialize(accounts[0])
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[For OpenZeppelin proxies](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies), the ABI and abi encode is not different when calling proxy vs. when calling implementation. For other proxy implementations, I cannot comment because you od not tell in your question how your proxy is created.

My assumption is that your proxy does not work.

Comment: It's actually an OpenZeppelin proxy. Running proxy directly for some functions on truffle test with mocha works but not when I call the proxy with an interface in my contract method.

Comment: One potential reason I can think off Is that proxy is initialised incorrectly and it sets some storage variables that are within the context of the wrong address.

Comment: But without seeing the code it is impossible to tell, it is just guesswork.

Comment: Let me update the code. Thanks.

Comment: Updated with how I deployed the contracts

Comment: The code looks good, so I cannot say what's wrong without using a debugger. Here is some related code for inspiration: https://github.com/Dawn-Protocol/dawn-erc20-erc777/blob/master/tests/proxy.ts#L60

Comment: Most likelty ` CONTRACT_WHEREPROXY_IS_CALLED.initialize(accounts[0])` should be ` PROXY_CONTRACT.initialize(accounts[0])`.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. Will take a look

Comment: Also I recommend OpenZeppelin SDK over Truffle, as Truffles "artefacts" deployment model is difficult to understand and apply outside very simple use cases.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

Remove the spaces in `"executeOrder(address, uint256, uint256)"`.

From [the official documentation about *Function Selector*](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.12/abi-spec.html#function-selector):

> The first four bytes of the call data for a function call specifies the function to be called. It is the first (left, high-order in big-endian) four bytes of the Keccak-256 hash of the signature of the function. The signature is defined as the canonical expression of the basic prototype without data location specifier, i.e. the function name with the parenthesised list of parameter types. **Parameter types are split by a single comma - no spaces are used**.

I have emphasized the part relevant to your question.

Comment: thanks for the correction but seems not to solve the main issue.

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah: It should solve one of the issues in your question.